# Icon next to text in react-select mutli label

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm using `react-select` and want icons to show next to the text of each label which can be added and removed via multiSelect.

```
const data = [
  { label: <svg /> && 'keyword one', value: 'keyword one' },
];
```

Only shows either the `svg` or the text. Does anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create your custom `Option` component.

Refer to this [link](https://react-select.com/components#defining-components) for Custom Option components :

Also, I have created this sample [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandboxer-example-forked-78280?file=/example.tsx) example. Pardon me for bad CSS styling.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `&&` the wrong way. See [short circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#short-circuit_evaluation) for more detail. `label` can also accept a `ReactNode`, to fix the problem, define the option array as follow:

```
const options = [
  {
    value: "ocean",
    label: (
      <>
        <YourIcon /> Ocean
      </>
    ),
    color: "#00B8D9",
    isFixed: true
  },
  {
    value: "blue",
    label: (
      <>
        <YourIcon /> Blue
      </>
    ),
    color: "#0052CC"
  },
  {
    value: "purple",
    label: (
      <>
        <YourIcon /> Purple
      </>
    ),
    color: "#5243AA"
  }
];
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]